# is there a way to control when the action of a form occurs with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Say we have got a form with an action for example :  `<form id="form" name="form" action="test.php">` Is there a way to control when will the action  occur even if i hit the submit button using Javascript?

Comment: PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: javascript i edited the post correctly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('form').on('submit', function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
             // other actions
           })
})
```

You should call event.preventDefault() when form submit, it function will cancel sumbmiting of the form, later in your scipt you can sumbit it from Javascript.

Comment: While this might provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the answer with some explanation of how and why this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

you can control it by deciding when you hit the button.

the `action` attribute of the `form` tag just dictates what handles the submitted info.  For a delay, or other fancy stuff you may want to incorporate some javascript into your front-end design.

here is a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)